# How to choose the parameter to scan in finding transition state by using Gaussian 16?

Tags: computational-chemistry, density-functional-theory

I have problems in finding the TS of reaction dehydrogenation of an organic compound. I read many tricks to find the TS and see scan is an effective method. As I know we can use the product of the reaction as a starting point to scan. But what parameter should I choose if there are two bonds were broken (the bonds in the red circles in the picture)?  I already tried to scan with one broken bond, and for the other one I just elongated it a little.  Unfortunately, the result has not converged. And one more question, does the orientation of the initial structure affect the result of the scan?
I am just a very new person in DFT as well as with Gaussian. Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Comment: By dehydrogenation, do you mean that H2 molecule is being ejected? Have you tried using QST2, or QST3? And also I am not sure what you mean by orientation of the initial structure. The structure can be rotated in any direction, it would not change anything.

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti yes, in dehydrogenation H2 molecules will be released. I already tried to use QST2 and QST3. But when I used the TS from those calculations to do IRC, the molecule at the forward and reverse side were not as my expectation. About the orientation of the initial structure, when I do the scan (relaxed redundant coord), I scan the bond length of atom 14 and 37 (as the picture), does the result will be affected by the position of atom 38? I mean if I do two scans with 2 different positions of atom 38 in the innitial structures, whether the results will be different?

Comment: What are the molecules that you get from the IRC from the TS of QST2/QST3? From what you have written, you are trying to model a concerted mechanism Since both atoms 37 and 38 are involved, different positions of atom 38 will definitely give different results. How much different I can't say.